# Drawer Layout stays open even after changing application

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

So i have a drawer layout inside Homepage of my activity it goes like this.

```
    public void settingDrawer() {
    if (drawer == null) {
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) navigationView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        navigationView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

it works just fine, but when i change activity and came back (using back button, or home button) the Drawer Layout stays open, i tried to close it when i use startActivity() method but it just doesn't right. i think there is a mistake that i made but i don't know where.

Comment: what do you expect? have you tried to close it in `onResume` instead of `startActivity`?

Comment: @MehranZamani i am sorry if what i expect doesn't make sense, and i tried to put it in onResume and it didnt run smoothly, but i think i get the idea of what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to Next Activity then first close Drawer like this

```
 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

so the above code will be close your drawer before navigating to next page and when you back to Activity then drawer is already closed.

Comment: it causes lag when the the drawer is closing.